# QTCPSocket can only connect to one of two networks?

Tags: qt, qt5

So one of my machines is actively connected to two totally seperate networks that are entirely disconnected from eachother.

Lets say the networks are 10.0.0.x, and 172.0.0.x.

Our application uses QTCPSocket to create a socket and connect to our server.

If that server is on a computer on the 10.0.0.x network, our application connects and performs as expected.

If that server is on a computer on the 172.0.0.x network, we will simply time out when we connect.

I then go into windows adapter settings and disable the adapter connecting to 10.0.0.x so that only the connection to 172.0.0.x is active on the system.
Now if i connect to the server on the 172.0.0.x network it connects and works as expected.

Why does our application seem to be binding to the first active network it finds?  I didnt write the code, but cant find anything in there that seems to be doing anything like this, so if you have any idea's what could be happening it would be greatly appreciated.

I'd like to stay connected to the 10.x network and the 172.x network at the same time and be able to connect to servers on both networks without having to enable/disable network ports.

Comment: I assume this is not just an issue with the configured routes in the system? Can you connect by other means? (Telnet, ssh, ping...)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes i can ping computers on both networks, and like i said if i disconnect one network i can connect to the other with QTCPSocket, but not if both networks are active.

Comment: Take a look at QAbstractSocket::socketDescriptor()